# How can I fire a Google analytics tag event on every form post?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to see statistics for forms submissions, grouped by type of forms. I am using Google Analytics 4 (https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/google-analytics/using-google-analytics-4x). I tried adding a GA event on form submit like this:

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add the tracking functionality to the form
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submission_tracking_handler';
}

function mymodule_form_submission_tracking_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  // some logic to check the form category 
  ...
  $event_data = [
    'event_category' => $category,
    'event_action' => 'Submit',
  ];
  $event_data_json = json_encode($event_data);
  $element = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'script',
    '#attributes' => [
      'type' => 'text/javascript',
    ],
    '#value' => "gtag('event', 'FormSubmit', $event_data_json);",
  ];
  $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
  $renderer->render($element);
}
```

But I can't see my event in the GA dashboard when checking real time reports. I also cleared the caches after adding the code. Maybe I should try adding some custom dimensions and metrics like this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets but I don't know where I should place my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the script execute? What does the browser console say? Did you try console logging the data? Is gtag a global function?

Comment: I added a console.log into the #value and I suppose the script is not executed, as nothing is logged. I've seen gtag is used in the GA script that was added in the <head> tag of the page, I assume it is global.

Comment: Your code does not attach anything to the form so I don't suppose it would ever work as written.

Comment: So what should I attach to the form? Should I move the gtag function into a js file and attach it to the form?

Comment: Simply rendering the code won't do anything, as Google Analytics acts on JS, so it it needs to be inserted into the page.